# Prevent wide header split into multiple lines for rmarkdown table

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to render an R markdown document using `rmarkdown::render()`. The header in one of the tables ends up being split into multiple lines although it only contains column headers consisting of single words. An example of the output is shown below.

[image]

There are 6 one-word labels and I would like them all to be on the same line.

I *think* it may be because the header is too wide and pandoc tried to prevent the table from being split altogether. If I remove, say, the last column then only one of the label is "moved up a line". Below I've added an Rmd-file that results in the image shown above if I render it using `rmarkdown::render()`.

```
---
title: trees
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
documentclass: report
---

### My header
The following table is of interest

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
&nbsp;                                                  character    factor    labelled   numeric    integer    logical
------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
Identify miscoded missing values                        $\times$    $\times$   $\times$   $\times$   $\times$

Identify prefixed and suffixed whitespace               $\times$    $\times$   $\times$

Identify levels with < 6 obs.                           $\times$    $\times$

Identify case issues                                    $\times$    $\times$

Identify missclassified numeric or integer variables    $\times$    $\times$

Identify outliers                                                                         $\times$   $\times$
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```